# Indenting a custom table view cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I have created a custom `UITableViewCell` using `Storyboard`. The cell contains 3 `UILabel` items. When the edit button is hit. The (-) sign slides in on the left but the cell does not indent and the (-) sign covers one of the UITextLabels.

I was wondering what is the best way to make all 3 `UITextLabels` indent when the edit button is hit. I have tried adding the 3 labels to a `UIView` (contentView) and adding it to the contentsView:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {

[super layoutSubviews];
[self.contentView addSubview:self.theContent];

}
```

Although this renders the same result. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What is the frame of theContent? Have you tried modifying the frame (subtracting from the 'x' value the amount you want it to be indented)? You can even do this in a nice animation:

```
[UIView beginAnimations : @"cell edit" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

CGRect frame = theContent.frame;
frame.origin.x -= 40; // add or subtract here however much you want to indent and in which direction
theContent.frame = frame;   

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I have not edited the frame. I was hoping that the cell's conentView would indent and all subviews would follow. This seems to be the case if you use a standard UITableViewCell. Perhaps i need to specify the above code in the    setEditing:animated: method in my UItableView subclass?

Comment: I tried entering the above code under the setEditing:animated: method. This made theContent view move but then pop straight back.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it in storyboard like this.
[image]